# Call powershell replace from batch file with variables

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

I need to replace a string by a user input in a xml file from a batch file, I made it working by using powershell "replace" command and calling it from the batch but I can't figure how to use batch variable inside the powershell command.

Working :

```
powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','somePassword' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
```

Not working :

```
set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','%pwd%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
```

Info : I'm on Windows 7

**Edit :**
With simpler script, it work so the problem seems to come from elsewhere in my script (the brightness part is working fine).

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /i "SSID"') do set "myssid=%%i" & goto next
:next
set "myssid=%myssid: =%"
if /i "%myssid%"=="someSSID" (
set "brightness=80"
 ) ELSE (
set "brightness=30"
set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','%pwd%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
pause
)
CALL "brightness.bat" "%brightness%"
```

The execution order between the test and real script seems different. Here is the working test script :

```
set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
echo %pwd%
powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','%pwd%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
pause
```

With it's output :

```
>set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
Enter pwd: hell
>echo hell
hell
>powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','hell' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
>pause
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

And the output of the full script :

```
>for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('netsh wlan show interface | findstr /i "SSID"') do set "myssid=%i"   & goto next
>set "myssid=mySSID"   & goto next
>set "myssid=mySSID"
>if /I "mySSID" == "SomeSSID" (set "brightness=80" )  ELSE (
set "brightness=30"
 set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
 powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
 pause
)
Enter pwd: 123
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Comment: Works for me. Are launching the `batch-file` from the same directory where you have `personalWifiProfile.xml` ?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes and it work fine without a variable as argument (first example) but with a variable it replace 'password' by nothing (it juste remove it)

Comment: Please show the output you get, as I said, I am not experiencing the same issue. also show the output of `echo "%pwd%"` as screenshot is fine.

Comment: @Gerhard Edited question accordingly.

Comment: ok, now that makes way more sense. You are setting and using a variable inside a parenthesized code block, so you need delayedexpansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require `delayedexpansion`, note the replacement of `%` with `!` in the variable as well `!pwd!`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if /I "mySSID" == "SomeSSID" (
      set "brightness=80"
   )  ELSE (
      set "brightness=30"
      set /p pwd="Enter pwd: "
      powershell -Command "(gc personalWifiProfile.xml) -replace 'password','!pwd!' | Out-File -encoding ASCII tempProfile.xml"
      pause
)
```

I only show part of the code relevant to your issue, so be sure you place `setlocal` enabledelayedexpansion` in the correct position, should you have other code blocks setting and using variables.

Comment: Thank you ! I had already tried `delayedexpansion` without success but I was missing the `!` around the variable.